# Will the Memory Allocator's Delayed Release Strategy Impair System Performance?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, glibc

I recently read some documentation about memory allocators like ptmalloc, tcmalloc, and others. They mentioned that it is a common practice for memory allocators to delay releasing memory back to the OS. This approach aims to avoid frequent system calls during future allocations.

However, I find this practice somewhat selfish. If every software application adopts this strategy, the OS might struggle to discern which memory regions are genuinely needed. Consequently, when the total requested memory exceeds the available hardware memory, the overall system performance could be adversely affected.

I am curious about the amount of unnecessary memory that current software applications typically request. Is there any research on this topic? Are there any published papers investigating this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> This approach aims to avoid frequent system calls during future allocations.

... thus reducing system CPU usage at the cost of using extra RAM.

> the OS might struggle to discern which memory regions are genuinely needed.

The OS will *not* struggle to discern that on any modern system -- it can use the page access bits to determine that.

If swap is present, the OS can page out any such not-recently-used memory.

> I am curious about the amount of unnecessary memory that current software applications typically request.

Define unnecessary. Is a 1% CPU reduction at the cost of using extra 1GiB or RAM necessary or not? It *depends*.

In large data centers, people (e.g. Google SREs) are constantly tuning `tcmalloc` parameters to achieve desired cost balance. Sometimes it's ok to spend a bit more time and save RAM, sometimes the opposite is true.

Comment: As to `unnecessary`:

If we call `resize(10)` on a `std::vector<int>` with `size() == 11`, then no freeing or allocation will occur. Thus the extra 1 int becomes unnecessary, but the underlying memory allocator still assumes it is in use.

Comment: @yhgu2000 Modern OSes manage memory in page-sized chunks. Releasing the "unnecessary" 4 bytes from an `std::vector<int>` is impossible _anyway_.

Comment: I know, but could it be possible that many a little makes a mickle?